# MySQL - Calculate time difference between events - LEFT JOIN, TIMEDIFF, MAX

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'log' with following example content:

```
table log
# id, event, client, starttime, endtime, response_time
'1', 'CALL', 'CLIENT 1', '2019-01-01 08:00:00', '2019-01-01 08:00:00', NULL
'2', 'SUPPORT', 'CLIENT 1', '2019-01-01 08:10:00', '2019-01-01 08:30:00', '00:10:00'
'3', 'CALL', 'CLIENT 2', '2019-01-01 08:20:00', '2019-01-01 08:20:00', NULL
'4', 'SUPPORT', 'CLIENT 1', '2019-01-01 08:45:00', '2019-01-01 08:55:00', NULL
```

The goal is to calculate the response_time between the last CALL event and the actual SUPPORT event.
I figured out following update statement:

```
UPDATE IGNORE log A
  LEFT JOIN log B
  ON B.id = A.id - 1
  SET A.response_time = TIMEDIFF(A.starttime, B.endtime)
  WHERE A.client = B.client
  AND B.event = 'CALL'
  AND A.status = 'SUPPORT'
  AND A.responsetime is NULL
```

But there are also SUPPORT events without a preceded CALL event (for example a planned SUPPORT doesn't have a CALL event). The response time of these events should stay NULL.

So for each SUPPORT record I'd need to calculate the time difference with the previous CALL event time unless the last event was also a SUPPORT event.

I tried to check if the previous event wasn't a SUPPORT event by adding:

```
AND B.id > (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(id)
          FROM log B
          WHERE client = A.client
              AND event = 'SUPPORT') as temp)
```

But this throws an error as A.client is unknown in the WHERE clause.

All help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: I think an OUTER JOIN in an UPDATE is a conceptually strange idea. Note that in this instance, your join manifests as an INNER JOIN, as `EXPLAIN EXTEND [your query]`  followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;` would demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a left join:

```
update ignore log a
left join log b on on b.id = a.id - 1 and a.client = b.client and b.event = 'call'
set a.response_time = timediff(a.starttime, b.endtime)
where a.status = 'support' and a.responsetime is null
```

If there is no corresponding record, the `left join` comes up empty, and `timediff()` receives a `null` value as second argument, resuling in a `null` result.

Comment: While perhaps not impossible, I find it unlikely that a LEFT JOIN would be required in an UPDATE query.

Comment: Thanks GMB. Extending the LEFT JOIN does work but I noticed that it only calculates the response time when a CALL is immediately followed by a SUPPORT event (id + 1). If there's another event in between (from another client) then the response time is also NULL due to the "b.id = a.id - 1" join I suppose. @Strawberry: Is an update without a join possible in this case?

Comment: @Jona I suspect that a join is required. I doubt that it needs to be an OUTER JOIN (LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a select statement which does the trick to join the previous CALL record to the following SUPPORT record and leaves other SUPPORT records without a preceded CALL event untouched:

```
SELECT * 
FROM log A
LEFT JOIN log B 
ON 
A.client = B.client 
AND B.status = 'CALL'
AND B.starttime < a.starttime
AND B.starttime > (IFNULL((SELECT MAX(C.starttime)
                           FROM log C
                           WHERE C.status = 'SUPPORT'
                           AND C.client = A.client
                           AND C.starttime > B.starttime 
                           AND C.starttime < A.starttime
                   ), '1999-01-01 00:00:00'))
WHERE A.Client = 'CLIENT 1'
AND A.status = 'SUPPORT'
AND A.response_time IS NULL
ORDER BY A.starttime;
```

But how can I convert this into a valid UPDATE statement for all clients? I struggle with the fact that I can't use the A.client and B.starttime in the WHERE clause of the subquery (Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.client' in 'where clause')

```
UPDATE IGNORE log A
LEFT JOIN log B 
ON 
A.client = B.client 
AND B.status = 'CALL'
AND B.starttime < a.starttime
AND B.starttime > ( IFNULL((SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(C.starttime)
                                           FROM log C 
                                           WHERE C.status = 'SUPPORT' 
                                           AND C.client = A.client 
                                           AND C.starttime > B.starttime
                                           AND C.starttime < A.starttime) 
                            AS temp),
                           '1999-01-01 00:00:00'))

SET A.wachttijd = TIMEDIFF(A.starttime, B.starttime), A.type = B.status

WHERE A.status = 'SUPPORT'
AND A.wachttijd IS NULL;
```